# Assigning attributes to nodes from attribute file

Tags: python, graph

I have a graph created from an edgelist. I also have an attribute file in this format

```
node_id1 attr1 attr2 ... attrM \n
node_id2 attr1 attr2 ... attrM \n
```

when I used this code

```
 self.G.nodes[vec[0]]['attr'] = np.array([float(x) for x in vec[1:]])
```

I encountered the following error

```
File "C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\networkx\classes\reportviews.py", line 178, in __getitem__   return self._nodes[n]
```

But when the graph is created from an adjacency list, the code doesnt give any error. Please what could be the problem?

Comment: Are you sure you want to set all the array to `attr`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to assign an attribute to non existent node:

```
>>> G.nodes[7]['attr'] = 8
# throws KeyError, similar to your description
```

And, in case it's added:

```
>>> G = nx.Graph()
>>> G.add_node(7)
>>> G.nodes[7]['attr'] = 8
>>> G.nodes(data=True)
NodeDataView({7: {'attr': 8}})
```

Comment: 890
855
911
839
78
923

Comment: It's hard to guess your issue without seeing what have you tried ([Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))

Answer (score 0):

node id in Graph:

```
890

855

911

839
```

when i try the following code

```
self.G.nodes[911]['attr'] = 8
```

it still gives me the same error even though the node is available

```
File "C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\networkx\classes\reportviews.py", line 178, in __getitem__
return self._nodes[n]
```

KeyError: 911